# Listing changes to records in a history database

Tags: sql

We have a home built database of hardware (sort of CMDB) which has a number of housekeeping tasks scheduled, tidying things up. There is a status associated with each hardware item - lets say for simplicity: Active; Inactive; Warehouse.

Every now and we get a jump in the numbers of 'Active' machines and we can't track which housekeeping task is causing this.

I've written a small script to run each night which takes a snapshot of the particular fields we are interested in (Standard Name of the hardware and Status) and appends them to a second 'trends' database each night with a date stamp, but I have no idea how to go about querying second database to produce a list of records where the status has either changed from or changed to the status 'Active' with an indication of the date.

(Once we have this list, when we get a big jump we can go and look individual records to see what housekeeping task caused the change.)

Does anyone have any thoughts on the SQL query I might use to try and check this, please?

Many thanks in advance for your comments!

(At the moment I am using sqlite3 but plan on moving to Oracle in the longer term. I'm doing the nightly dump with a Python 3.7 script)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to do it. For the record in case anyone is interested, I created two sql queries:

```
select * from Trends_Database where (
Machine_Name in (select Max(Machine_Name) from Trends_Database group by Machine_Name) AND
(Status LIKE 'Deployed') AND
(date(`Date of Snapshot`) == date('now')))
```

and

```
select * from Trends_Database where (
Machine_Name in (select Max(Machine_Name) from Trends_Database group by Machine_Name) AND
(Status NOT LIKE 'Deployed') AND
(date(`Date of Snapshot`) == date('now','-1 day'))
```

I read these into a couple of Pandas dataframes and took the intersection of the two.

I got the bones of it from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39684477/sqlite-return-all-columns-for-max-of-one-column-without-repeats)